# What does $\mathbb{R}$-invariant mean for a measure?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, A, m)$ be a measure space with m being $\mathbb{R}$-invariant.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

In general, an object can be invariant under a particular action of a group (such as $\mathbb R$)  on a space it's a member of.  Without specifying how the group is supposed to act on the space, it may be hard to guess what is meant.  I would
suspect this is referring to some one-parameter group of symmetries of $X$.